# Is a paragraph inaccessible when it contains only a button?

Tags: forms, accessibility, html

[Tenon.io](http://tenon.io) marked this code as invalid, because it is a "paragraph without text in it".

```
<p class="dataform-submit">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit request" />
</p>
```

Is this code really "inaccessible"? Which semantic block tag should be used for containing a submit button (and, in general, parts of a form)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not inaccessible.

I don’t think that [`p`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) is the most appropriate¹ element here, because this button doesn’t really represent the "typical" [paragraph](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#paragraph), but the markup choice shouldn’t affect accessibility at all in this case. It’s an issue of semantic markup, not accessibility.

Every capable user agent should be able to handle a `p` that contains text and a button (which is a combination that can make sense in many cases). Removing the text from this doesn’t suddenly change something fundamentally, so there’s no reason to assume that there exists a user agent that wouldn’t be able to handle it anymore.

¹ I’d use no parent element at all, or if one is needed for styling purposes, a meaningless [`div`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-div-element).

Comment: I would also add that <button> is preferable to an <input> element, as long as we're being semantically correct!

Comment: @unor: I have an aversion to mixed by-default inline elements and by-default block level elements contained by the same parent.

Comment: @DávidHorváth: I can relate to that ;) I’d use a `div` then (just like for each label+input pair, assuming that it’s a form like that).

Answer (score 1):

Your paragraph is not empty and the explanation provided on Tenon is not applicable here:

> A paragraph was found without text in it. While this tends to have a low severity, it does create an unnecessary nuisance for users of screen readers who are likely to hear the announcement of the empty paragraph as they navigate through content. If this empty paragraph exists to behave as margin, use CSS for this purpose instead.

Your `input` has a text replacement string and the algorithm should consider it.

This is a bug. And this test is quite a nonsense, as there won't be any difference for a screenreader if a `div` was used here.